# Accessing Laravel Api using POSTMAN (404 not found)

Tags: laravel, postman

I wrote an API for User Login using Laravel 5.8

When I tested the Login on Postman, it generated an error.

> Status: 404 Not Found.

The File Path is `Http->Controllers->UserController->Login`

The project is laravelapi. I used POST in Postman and added this:

```
http://localhost/laravelapi/public/user/api/login
```

But when I run php artisan serve and used:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/login
```

Status was OK.

**Controller**

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->json()->all();

    try {
        if(! $token == JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
        }
    } catch(JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

**api.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');
```

What do I do to make `http://localhost/laravelapi/public/user/api/login` work and have Status: `OK`

Thanks.

Comment: link should be http://localhost/laravelapi/public/api/login

Comment: It works like magic. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

link must be localhost/laravelapi/public/api/login